2 in 1: Twin Puzzle
Below there are 2 separate puzzles, only containing 15 black and 15 white dots each. They may look the same, but the puzzles are different. Your job is to find both solutions.
But how are the 2 puzzles connected?
Well, I think you'll know once you have solved at least one of them.

If you do have the answer, please share which puzzle you solved first :)

Coincidence? I think NOT!

To save a thousand words:

 (I noticed the braille first)


I feel like I'm being stupid, but I can't quite see how the Braille pattern is translated into the individual braille characters. Could someone make an edit that clarifies this, I'm intrigued.

@ConnieMnemonic: white: dot, 3 blacks: dash

@Themoonisacheese I understand how the Morse component is translated, that's fine. It's the Braille component I don't understand.

@ConnieMnemonic The single left-to-right line is transformed into 3 left-to-right, top-to-bottom lines. i.e. The first two dots are the top, the second 2 are the middle dots, and the last two are the bottom dots.

@MannerPots Ahah, understanding has dawned, thank you!
